# Idm picketlink list roles of a group is building up lot of queries, FetchMode and Fettype has no impact

Tags: picketlink

> RelationshipQuery query = rm.createRelationshipQuery(Grant.class);
>           query.setParameter(Grant.ASSIGNEE, groups.toArray(new Group[groups.size()]));
>           return query.getResultList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did some RCA and found that the entire entity is getting loaded  and it is a performance hit, hence create native queries to get groupRoles .